# Access deleted questions

Tags: discussion, questions, deleted-questions

I just recently deleted my question because they had negatives votings I was obliged to delete them. Fortunately, I star this kind of questions so I can always access them again.

Now I imagine there are also some similar deleted questions which might be very helpful. My question is if there's a way to search in deleted questions too.
Thank you

Comment: You want to be able to search potentially useful, but deleted, questions and you are surprised that you can't. Even when you admit doing that yourself. `</irony>`

Comment: I don't understand the question. You want to access *your* deleted questions, *other people's* deleted questions, or *all* deleted questions? Also I don't understand what *"similar deleted questions which might be very helpful"* means. Do you mean you think they would be helpful because they were also deleted, so you could see how to avoid having to delete questions in future? or just that they would be useful because they're on the same general topic?

Answer (score 17):

> But because they had negatives votings I was obliged to delete them.

No. No you aren't.

Stack Overflow is not here to provide you answers so that you can immediately delete them. Honestly, the way you describe what you've done feels abusive. I have a moderator message template for that too:

> You have recently removed or defaced a lot of content from your posts. Please note that once you post a question or answer to this site, those posts become part of the collective efforts of others who have also contributed to that content. Posts that are potentially useful to others should not be removed except under extraordinary circumstances. Even if the post is no longer useful to the original author, that information is still beneficial to others who may run into similar problems in the future - this is the underlying philosophy of Stack Exchange.
>
> Extensive deletions take a lot of effort to repair.

Reconsider your actions. Just because you've received a downvote doesn't mean you should delete the question. This is especially true if you are receiving good answers.

---

To answer your question: No. You can't search deleted questions. They are *deleted*.

Comment: I don't think its unreasonable for new users to think deleting heavily downvoted questions is the right course of action. There are even badges for deleting questions. Maybe StackOverflow is not clear enough that deleting questions should *almost* never happen. Especially if others have given answers.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic maybe some of our user base isn't invested enough to value our core principles. Or do you really think they read this in the tour: *we're working together to build a library of deleted answers*

Comment: @rene I'm just saying it could be made more clear. I don't think its fair to have new users infer core principles from one small line on a multi-page tour. It should be made explicit that deleting your question is almost never the right thing to do.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic don't be misled by the user's displayed reputation on this question. They are not a new user. They've also asked on meta about deleting questions before.